# How to make an existing task depend on a custom task

Tags: scala, sbt

I am writing a custom task in SBT. I want the existing task of "test" depend on my custom task.

Basically, I want my custom task to execute just before someone calls "test" on my project.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine test so that is depends on your task:

```
lazy val foo = taskKey[Unit]("...")
foo := println("Hello, world!")
test <<= test in Test dependsOn foo
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I will try your suggestion. Can you tell me what does `<<=` mean in SBT? I posted this as a separate question. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104892/what-does-mean-in-sbt Can you please answer it?